# Why does the program looks different when run in IDE and when executed from command promt?

Tags: javafx

//Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        MainController mc = new MainController();
        if (mc != null){
            System.out.println("It is not NULL");
        }else System.out.println("There is nothing");

        try {
            //BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

// MainController.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainController {

    @FXML                                                                  // members are accessible to markup connects scene builder with MainController
    private Label myMessage;

    public void generateRandom(ActionEvent event){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int myRand = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;                          // generate random number b/w 1 and 50
        myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(myRand));
        //System.out.println(Integer.toString(myRand));                      // convert integer to string

    }
}
```

// Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="443.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="clickme" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="273.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateRandom" text="Click Here" />
        <Label fx:id="myMessage" layoutX="113.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="186.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

// application.css

```
#clickme{
    -fx-font-size: 30px;
    -fx-background-color: rgba (255, 255, 255, .80);
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-padding: 6 6 6 6;
    -fx-border-radius: 8;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

The thing is when i run this code in IntelliJ this is the output 
[output from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk9G2.png)

and the output when I run it from command prompt
[output from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJRo.png)

I am not sure why this is happening and I would like to know how to fix it so that when i run the code from command prompt I get the same output as I do from the IDE

Comment: Have you looked at the output of your command prompt, there's clearly some errors there from your screenshot

Comment: The warnings also shows up in IDE as well but even then the button is present

Comment: What warning to you get? I get a css warning and it resolves if you change `-fx-background-color: rgba (255, 255, 255, .80);` to `-fx-background-color: #ffffffcc;` in your application.css file..

Comment: Is that space between `rgba` and the `(` the issue? Please include that output in your command line as (formatted) text in your question. Also, it might help to know which JDK version(s) you are using in each case.

Comment: @James_D yes, as you pointed out the space between rgba and ( resolves the warning issue but when i run the code it opens a new window with no "Click here" button that I created. So the original problem still persists. I am using jdk 14.0.1

Comment: @micpog90 when I changed the code to yours the warnings went away but the button is still not present when I execute from command line.

Comment: @M.Sajid maybe you have two different java versions installed on your pc and you start different ones from your IDE and your command line...